# Segment fault C program dynamic 2D array for social media database

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

2 days no progress.  I get a segment fault when I try to print on CLion or Visual Studio code but not on other online compilers... why? How to fix: 
https://repl.it/join/epycryqd-joelortiz :here works fine.
I am trying to build a social media database that requires dynamic memory allocation.
I am parsing out the following input.txt file.
user_IDS are have a # after the ID these will be placed all vertically in the first column.
The users friends list will be without a # and will be placed after first column across the row.

To sum up:

- First column user ID .horizontal.
- All rows users friends. vertical.

My code works on any online compiler just not on anything else.....results in segment fault and a bunch of zeros.......what is going wrong?

input.txt

```
123456#
654321#
000007#
000666#
000007 123456
000666 000007
000111#
987654#
654321 000111
987654 000111
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    FILE * input_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    int number;
    char str[100];
    // read every string from input file
    int **ptr; // to store the user and his/her friends in multi-dimensional array
    // first column stores user ID and rest of the column stores his friend list
    int *row; // to store the number of columns in each row
    int rowSize = 2; // inital size
    ptr = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * rowSize); // allocating memory
    row = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * rowSize);
    int i = -1; // to keep track of current row
    int colSize = 2; // initial size of col, we increment if it gets full
    int j = 0; // to keep track of col
    while(fscanf(input_file, "%s", str) != EOF)
    {
        //check if the string has '#' at the end then the take characters before the # and convert it to integer
        if(i == rowSize)
        {
            rowSize *= 2;
            ptr = realloc(ptr, rowSize*sizeof(int*));
            row = realloc(row, rowSize*sizeof(int));
        }
        if(str[strlen(str) - 1] == '#')
        {
            if(i != -1)
            {
                row[i] = j;
            }
            j = 1;
            i++;
            colSize = 2;
            ptr[i] = (int *)malloc(colSize*sizeof(int));
            sscanf(str, "%d", &number);
            ptr[i][0] = number;
        }
        else if(str[strlen(str) - 1] != '#')
        {
            if(j == colSize)
            {
                colSize *= 2;
                ptr[i] = realloc(ptr[i], rowSize*sizeof(int));
            }
            sscanf(str, "%d", &number);
            ptr[i][j] = number;
            j++;
            //row[i] = j;
        }
    }

    fclose(input_file);
    printf("Format\n");
    printf("[User ID] -> [Friend1], [Friend2] . . .\n\n");
    for(int ii = 0; ii <= i; ii++)
    {
        printf("%d -> ", ptr[ii][0]);
        for(int jj = 1; jj < row[ii]; jj++)
            printf("%d, ", ptr[ii][jj]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger to help you. For starters, the debugger will give you the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault. And it can do much more such as stepping thru the code and examining state. There are also tools like `valgrind` if you are using linux that helps with finding memory problems (which is likely what you are facing).

Comment: Also, please fix up the indentation of the posted code. You are much more likely to get an answer if you make the code readable for others.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that when `j == colSize`, you double `colSize`, then resize `ptr[i]` based off of `rowSize`.  That's using the incorrect variable.

Comment: Thank fixed  the variable error. The debugger points to the problem having to do with my initial value for rowSize and occurs sometimes when the following condition is true           if(i == rowSize). I just starting programing with dynamic memory so I have no clue how to fix it.